# I am trying to download html String coming from backend as PDF file but for long string it is not working properly but fine for 1-2 page

Tags: reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using this code for downloading it is working for small html string but as string gets bigger it starts giving blank pages.
currently trying combination of html2Canvas and jsPDF libraries.

```
  function downloadFile() {
    const element = document.getElementById('html-content-div').innerHTML;
    //make setup for pdf page and content
    const option = {
      margin:       0,
      filename:     payload?.fileName.replace('.html','.pdf'),
      //image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
      html2canvas:  { scale: 2 },
      jsPDF: {
          unit: 'pc',
          format: 'a4',
          orientation: 'portrait',
          layout: 'continuous',
          imageData: 'Uint8Array',
          // Add these lines to handle line breaks and CSS styling
          lineHeight: 1.4,
          fontSize: 14,
        },
         pagebreak: {
          mode :["css"],
          before: 'page-break-before',
          avoid: ['h2', 'h3', 'h4','p', '.field',"table"],
        },
    };
   html2pdf().from(element).set(option).save();
  }
  
// below is the code of div I am targeting to download.
 
   <div id='html-content-div' ref={reportTemplateRef} style={{ padding: "20px" }} contentEditable="false"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} >
          </div>
```

I have tried dividing string into parts and converting them into HTML and that worked but didn't found any way to combine and make them into one.
Can anyone suggest where am I doing wrong or what approach do I need to follow to get html converted properly into PDF